# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3716

Tags: next.js

I just installed next js using the command `npx create-next-app@latest ./` . It just threw the error out of the box.
The error log in the terminal is like this.

```
- event compiled client and server successfully in 4.1s (567 modules)
- error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:37169
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1574:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 37169
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade to NodeJS v16 for the time being.

This is a known bug on some Linux distros and is being looked into currently.

See [this issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49526) for progress and related info.

Comment: I used turbopack instead. It resolved the issue for now.